# Angular2 Template driven form with HTML table

Tags: html, angular

I want to use template driven form in table tr like < tr #formAdd="ngForm" >. This will allow me to have separate form for each row.

When i try to do so, I am getting below error

> zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: There
>   is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("/thead>
>               
>                 ]#formAdd="ngForm">

Comment: please edit what you really want to do..

Comment: Sorry. Updated, let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: You can't use the ngForm export like that everywhere, it's just added to the <form> by default. maybe you can add an ngForm attribute additionally to your <tr> to use it as you intend to... have a look at the selectors for ngForm: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.3.0/modules/%40angular/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L27-L159